# Systemd Service for Offlineimap + gpg encrypted PW's inside tmux works manually after system start but not autmoatically

Tags: systemd, email, gpg-agent, offlineimap

### Short description, what i'm searching for:

I want to have a detached tmux session automatically started as a systemd user service. Inside that, offlineimap should start and decrypt my login credentials. The graphical variant of pinentry should ask me for the password for decrypting my login credentials, when I attach to the session.
For managing my login credentials, I want to use the program [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/).

### What I've got so far:

The desired Behavior works perfectly and reproducibly (starting from reboot), when i start the user service after I've logged into my system.

But unfortunately it doesn't work when I do "symstemctl --user enable mail.service" and reboot:

```
$ systemctl --user status mail
● mail.service - load offlineimap for all mail accounts inside tmux
Loaded: loaded (/home/toogley/.dotfiles/systemd/user/mail.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)

$ tmux attach-session -t mail
can't find session mail
```

I have no idea, what i could analyze or what might be the reason. Does somebody has tips how to address this issue?

Thanks a lot!

**My  mail.service**

```
Description=load offlineimap for all mail accounts inside tmux
After=network.target graphical.target
Requires=gpg-agent.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s mail -n dev 'export GPG_TTY=$(tty) && \
offlineimap'
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux kill-window -t mail
ExecReload=/usr/bin/kill -s USR1 $(pgrep offlineimap)

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

**my gpg-agent.service:**

```
[Unit]
Description=GnuPG private key agent
IgnoreOnIsolate=true

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gpg-agent --daemon --homedir=%h/.gnupg
ExecStop=/usr/bin/pkill gpg-agent
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

**My ~/.offlineimaprc**

```
[general]
accounts = dev
ui = ttyui
metadata = ~/.dev_offimap
pythonfile=~/.dotfiles/mutt/accounts/decrypt.py

[Account dev]
synclabels = yes
localrepository = dev-local
remoterepository = dev-remote
status_backend = sqlite
autorefresh = 1
quick = 10

[Repository dev-local]
type = Maildir
localfolders = ~/mail/dev/

[Repository dev-remote]
remotepasseval = get_pass("toogley@mailbox.org")
ssl = yes
type = IMAP
remotehost = imap.mailbox.org
remoteuser = toogley@mailbox.org
sslcacertfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
keepalive = 60
holdconnectionopen = yes
```

Comment: does `journalctl --user` give any clues?

Comment: in your `mail.service` you have `After=network.target graphical.target` and
`WantedBy=graphical.target` which I dont think is workable.

Comment: @meuh : Thanks for your suggestions - they were very helpful in finding the problem :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what I'm searched for is currently not possible.

Initially I misread the description of `graphical.target` - I thought this target would be set after the login has happened. Instead, it just sets up the Login Screen (e.g. lightdm). And for "logged into graphical desktop" does currently no target exist.

[The ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Window_manager) describes a method of starting the window manager per systemd user services - which doesn't work for me, because it depends when  the user logs into lightdm.

**As a workaround** I use an alias for starting my service when I need it.